# Sorting nested dictionaries python

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to solve this issue with sorting a particular nested dictionary.

Structure is as follows:

```
dct = {
    "test": {
        0: [1, 3],
        1: [5, 6],
    },
    "test2": {
        7: [9],
        3: [4, 6],
    }
}
```

I would love to be able to sort by the "test" term and the key so in the "test2" I would have first 3 and then 7.

I have tried this

```
arr = OrderedDict(sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])))
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to perform this kind of sort?

Comment: Wait, how is `test2` related to `test` here?

Comment: @KaushikNP Basically there is a dictionary, which has keys "test" and "test2". Each of these keys holds as a value that inner dictionary.  So for instance dict["test"] = {0: [1,3], 1:[5,6]}

Comment: Basically, sort according to key in your dictionary right?

Comment: @Kaushik NP basically sort by key and then sort by key again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want outer dict and all inner dicts sorted, then you need an *OrderedDict* of *OrderedDict*s. You can create it with something like

```
OrderedDict(sorted((k, OrderedDict(sorted(v.items()))) for k,v in dct.items()))
```

Answer (score 2):

So basically since `keys` need to be `sorted` in the `nested dict`, go through the dictionary and transfer the data to a new dictionary.

```
>>> new_d = OrderedDict()

>>> for key,val in d.items():                      #go through the dictionary
        new_d[key] = OrderedDict(sorted(val.items()))       #sort according to keys
```

#driver values

```
IN : d
{
  'test' :{   0:[1,3] ,  
              1:[5,6] 
          }, 
  'test2':{ 7:[9],  
            3:[4,6]
          }
}

OUT : new_d 
OrderedDict([('test', {0: [1, 3], 1: [5, 6]}), ('test2', {3: [4, 6], 7: [9]})])
```

**Edit :** As the OP wants the dictionary's **initial keys** (EX : `test3:{ ... } , test2:{ ... }` ) to be sorted too, the below changes need to be done :

```
>>> initial_sort = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
>>> inital_sort
OrderedDict([('test2', {7: [9], 3: [4, 6]}), ('test3', {0: [1, 3], 1: [5, 6]})])

>>> new_d = OrderedDict()

>>> for key,val in initial_sort.items():                      #go through the first key sorted dictionary 
         new_d[key] = OrderedDict(sorted(val.items()))
```

#driver values

```
IN : d = {'test3': {0: [1, 3], 1: [5, 6]}, 'test2': {7: [9], 3: [4, 6]}}
OUT : new_d = OrderedDict([('test2', OrderedDict([(3, [4, 6]), (7, [9])])), ('test3', OrderedDict([(0, [1, 3]), (1, [5, 6])]))])
```

Comment: Yeah, I am using python 2.7